# Graphics Calculator for Computer Science applications

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computer-science, education, calculator

I'm looking for a really good, modern, standalone calculator; something particularly suited for engineering and/or computer science (as an educational tool).

• I started with a basic Texas Instruments TI-30XB (the green one).
• Then I bought a Casio FX-100+; for Base-n Conversion (bin, oct, dec, hex) and for calculating Combinations & Permutations.
• Then I bought a Casio FX-991EX Classwiz; for Matrix Operations (multiplying matrices, etc).

But they're limited in what they can do.
For instance, they can't do:
• Matrices greater than 3x3.
• Matrix inversion.
• Binary fractions.
• BCD (binary coded decimal).
• Signed integers/bytes (2's complement, etc).

Additionally, I'm looking for something suitable for the following kinds of operations:
• Sets (incl. Functions & Relations): ∪Union, ∩Intersection, ∁Complement, etc.
• Logic (incl. Logic Gates & Boolean Algebra): ∧AND, ∨OR, ¬NOT, ∀, ∃, ∈, etc.
• Venn Diagrams.
• Logic Gate Diagrams.
• Truth Tables.
• Karnaugh Maps.

Does something like this even exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Just get a laptop and MAPLE and you will have a standalone "calculator" with everything you could ever want.

Comment: Most if not all "*graphing*" calculators include full support for matrices of any size.  As for set operations and venn diagrams and the like., you'd probably be better off doing problems related to those by hand as I've never heard of a calculator (*or even a computer program*) attempting to generalize the problem as much as would be required in any introductory course on the topic.  The actual process of doing those manipulations by hand are rarely difficult, the majority of the difficulty in just being able to understand what is being asked.

Comment: @JMoravitz There are plenty, scattered around the web, etc. WolfRam Alpha has some decent ones, for instance.

Comment: @tjt263 for finite sets perhaps.  I haven't seen one personally which can even handle something like $\{1,2,3\}\cup [2,5)$ for example.

Comment: @Bruce & Moo A dedicated device would be preferable, but I will check these out. I haven't heard of them before, only MATLAB, Mathematica, etc.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, I doubt I'll get all the things I mentioned. But I'd settle for some.